# How to migrate a database from a local to a remote server?

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres db that I have created and need to deploy remotely. From reading online I have understood that to do that I need to modify the following files :

1. pg_hba.conf
2. postgresql.conf

From what I read I need to modify them and somehow add them to my database?

My question is:

1. How do I modify the 2 files to deploy a database online? I read the documentation but its too complicated for my understanding.(ie what is needed and why?)
2. How do I add them to my database online? My idea was to create a database dump of the local DB, then push the dump on a new database on the remote computer, but how do these 2 files fit in there? Where should there be placed? I cannot find details on this.

note. I have never done distributed programming before, my question might be naive but I really have no idea how to proceed.

I am using osX operating system,but will be using linux on the remote computer.

Comment: your question is lacking details. specify which operating system you are using and what have you tried so far? Are there multiple machines or a single machine where you need to deploy? Also, postgres by default does not allow connecting from a remote address so for that you need to change pg_hba.conf file. Check the examples at bottom of this page http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Answer (score 8):

The two configuration files apply to the server, so both your local and remote server already have those files and their contents is specific to the installation.

Assuming your remote server is already up and running, all you need to do is dump the database you want to deploy to a file and then load the dump file in your remote server. You do not have to do anything with the configuration files.

You can use [`pg_dump`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html) to dump the local database to file, doing something like this:

```
pg_dump -U postgres -Fc my_db > my_db.db
```

But check all the options of the `pg_dump` program.

Loading the database on your remote server is just as easy with [`pg_restore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html):

```
pg_restore -h <ip remote server> -p <port remote server> -U postgres -C my_db.db
```

On the remote server you need to specify a user who can create databases, if you do not have access to the `postgres` role.

If you are on some flavour of *nix you can even pipe `pg_dump` output into `pg_restore` input and do it all in one go:

```
pg_dump -U postgres -Fc my_db | pg_restore -h <ip> -p <port> -U postgres -C
```

Note that `pg_dump` will ask for a password on the *local server* (if at all) and `pg_restore` will for a password on the *remote server* (if at all).

Both programs have a lot of options. Be sure to **read the documentation fully** and use options to match your situation before coming back to tell me that it doesn't work.

Comment: My remote server has postgres running,but not my db yet. Like you said I i will use my db dump to do so. MY doubt is how do I acheive remote access? i mean how do I modify these 2 files so I can access my db on the remote computer?

Comment: You do not change those files, you just use pgAdmin or any other tool that you use on your local computer. Just point the app to the remote server instead of your local server.

Comment: ok! So i just create a new db using my dump and point to hostname and port there am I right?

Comment: things is I am using ant to deploy my project, and I will be using some kind of python/bash script to intialize my db on a remote computer, I cannot use any kind of gui here. So everthing needs to be from command line.